# Href in laravel foreach only return the last record in array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

href return last return last row in an array

Comment: please, format the code example, otherwise, we can't see it properly :)

Comment: Did you check the values in  the database? Check if the values are inserted the correct way.

Comment: Above employerName,  jobRole, contactPerson records show right??  Please explain

Comment: is the problem in ```<a href="/empProfileHistory/{{$emphistory->historyId}}/{{$emphistory->employeeId}}">``` or ```<a href="/DeleteEmployee/{{$emphistory->historyId}}">```?

Comment: problem is with,<a href="/empProfileHistory/{{$emphistory->historyId}}/{{$emphistory->employeeId}}">

Comment: Please show your `route`.

Comment: @phpdeveloper Your route defines perfectly. Now how to update records in a controller? Please show the controller logic.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, i am using this routing syntax which works for me

```
<a href="{{URL::to('empProfileHistory/'.$emphistory->historyId.'/'.$emphistory->employeeId)}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded waves-effect btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a>
                <a href="{{URL::to('DeleteEmployee/'.$emphistory->historyId)}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded waves-effect btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a>
```

Comment: please check for the historyId and employeeId in other rows, whether it is available in blade for rest of the row.